# Malware Samples that defeats emulators by using uncommon API calls

Tags: malware, emulation, sandbox

I am looking for a few malware samples that detects sandboxes using uncommon API calls. I understand that one of the drawbacks of OS emulated sandboxes is that the malware can use uncommon API calls to crash the emulator/sandboxes. Does anyone know of such samples? It would be great if different samples asking for different APIs could be supplied.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about reverse-engineering.  It's sample collection.

Comment: @peterferrie Is there some other forum/website where I can ask for such help if it is deemed as off-topic here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with this directly, so take it with a grain of salt. If you take a look at what Sandboxie does, on top of their driver they also have a huge number of ring3 hooks on WinAPI. There are also lots of other things to check for, even as simple as their module being loaded. Point being that I don't think an individual example will really do much good because there are so many countless ways to detect it. The same goes for other sandbox emulation, VM's, etc.

Comment: I am actually looking for malware with specific techniques in order to test it against different sandbox architecture as part of a research project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the samples but here's the report on the malware which does sandbox detection: https://www.root9b.com/sites/default/files/whitepapers/PoS%20Malware%20ShellTea%20PoSlurp_1.pdf so that you can be more specific in your samples search.